# ¿Como manipular el metodo indexOf()? Java

Tags: java, string

Tengo que hacer que la **i** de la siguiente palabra ="**Otorrinolaringólogo**" , se encuentre en la posicion **6**.

Pero como la i en realidad esta en la posición **5** , querría saber como manipularlo dentro del metodo `indexOf`.

Intente hacerlo pero me sigue tirando que esta en la posicion 5 :

```
 String palabra = "Otorrinolaringólogo";
 Integer posicion=0;


 System.out.println(palabra.indexOf('i' ,posicion+1));
```

Tambien intente utilizar junto con el `charAt()`:

```
System.out.println(palabra.charAt(posicion+1).indexOf('i'));
System.out.println(palabra.indexOf('i',charAt(posicion+1)));
```

y me tira error que no se puede invocar el metodo `indexOf(char)` en un tipo primitivo `char`.

No se me ocurre de que otra forma hacerlo.

Comment: No puede manipular el funcionamiento de `indexOf()`. Siempre busca el string empezando con el indice 0. Lo que puede hacer es como asi: `Integer x = palabra.indexOf('i')+1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la palabra "Otorrinolaringólogo", la posición de la i se encuentra como comentas en la letra 6 pero al usar el método [indexof()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) este indica:

> **[indexof()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) Devuelve el índice (iniciando con 0) dentro de esta cadena de la primera
>   aparición de la subcadena especificada.**

En este caso la letra "i" se encuentra en el indice 5, si deseas obtener la posición dentro de la cadena, simplemente suma 1, ejemplo:

```
 String palabra = "Otorrinolaringólogo";
 //Busca posición de letra "i".
 System.out.println(palabra.indexOf('i')+1);
```

salida:

```
6
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora si funciona :D !!!

Comment: Excelente me da gusto, saludos @computer96

Answer (score 2):

Como te comentan en otras respuestas las posiciones en java empiezan en el 0.

es decir

`O-T-O-R-R-I-N-O-L-A-R--I--N--G--O--L--O--G--O`

`0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18`

Si quieres cambiar la I a la posición siguiente, debes tener en cuenta que la I se encuentra en la posición 5.

Con respecto a las lineas que te producen error, el motivo es:

```
System.out.println(palabra.charAt(posicion+1).indexOf('i'));
```

En este caso estas intentando realizar el `indexOf` con el resultado de `palabra.charAt(posicion+1)` lo cual seria intentar realizar un `indexOf` sobre un `char`, y este método no esta disponible en el objeto `char`.

```
System.out.println(palabra.indexOf('i',charAt(posicion+1)));
```

En este caso, lo primero te faltaria poner "palabra." antes del `charAt` y `indexOf` y no funcionaria como esperas que lo haga.

**lo que quieres sería:**

```
System.out.println(palabra.indexOf('i' )+1);
```

---

Si lo que necesitas es modificar las posiciones de las letras

Teniendo un `String` podrías cambiar a `char` `array` para modificar las posiciones.

Te adjunto un ejemplo en código de un método que intercambia posiciones.

```
public static String cambiarLetras (String cadena, int posLetraInicial,  int posLetraFinal){

    char[] charArray = cadena.toCharArray();

    char tempChar = charArray[posLetraFinal];
    charArray[posLetraFinal] = charArray[posLetraInicial];
    charArray[posLetraInicial] = tempChar;

    return String.valueOf(charArray);
}
```